# email regex issue

Tags: regex, validation, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I have a regular expression that validates email addresses:

```
/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/
```

It fails on these types though:

```
a.whatever@whatever.com
```

When the `.` before the `@` is preceded by a single character the validation fails. I'm new to regular expressions, can someone help me allow those types of email addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `+` quantifier to `*`:

```
/^[A-z_][A-z0-9_]*([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/
-----------------^
```

Note: I also changed `[^0-9]` to `[A-z_]`, which makes more sense in terms of your rules.

Comment: Correct. The problem was with the '+' meaning that the original regex required at least two characters before the dot.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches the uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters, *plus* the six punctuation characters whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.  So it's equivalent to ```[A-Z\[\\\]^_`a-z]```.  I thought you were ready for the rice paper test, Tim, but I guess it's back to "wax on, wax off" for you. :D

Comment: @AlanMoore:  I was just copying the already defined character class OP was using.  I've updated my answer to clarify your point.  Thanks for the note!

Comment: So, do you believe the OP really wanted to match square brackets, backslashes, etc. in addition to letters?  Using `[A-z]` as a shorthand for all letters is a common error among regex beginners, and by copying it without comment you're validating it.